# iWork'08 sumifs equivalent in Numbers

Tags: iwork, numbers

Does iWork '08 have a `sumifs` type command? If not, how can I sum on multiple conditions? Essentially how do I fo the following:

```
=sumifs(A$2:A$20,B$2:B$20,"<10",C$2:C$20,"female)
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers 09 has the [SUMIFS](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH803?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) function, which operates the same as in Excel. Numbers 08 [does not appear](http://curmi.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/functions-in-excel-and-numbers-09.pdf) to have it, but it has `SUMIF`.

You should still be able to do what you are trying by combining two logical statements.

Without using the function, you could also build a new column by multiplying values by a logical statement. For example:

```
=A3 + A4 × (B4>2)
```

This will only add `A4` if `B4` is greater than 2...

Or in your example, make a column using `AND`:

```
=A2 x AND(B2<10,exact(C2,"female))
```

Then sum that column. Values that don't meet both criteria will be zero.